# Problem with Spring MVC Controller and Servlet error [ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

servlet not doing redirect, used Spring Boot 2.4.1. Code and comments below.

Class servlet

`code`

```
    @WebServlet(name = "estore",
                urlPatterns = {"/"},
                loadOnStartup = 1)
     public class EstoreServlet extends HttpServlet {
            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
                 IOException{                                            
                     // Here logic and after need redirect
                     response.sendRedirect("/index.html");
           }
     }
```

Information from request

`code`

```
   Session - org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2e555cdd
   Servlet path - /
   Server name - localhost
   Local name - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
   Local addr - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
   Get Remote user - null
   Get method - GET
   Get protocol - HTTP/1.1
   Get content type - null
   Get server port - 8080
   Get sheme - http
   Get Request URI - /
   Get Context Path -
```

Spring MVC configuration file

`code`

```
@Configuration
@ServletComponentScan(basePackages = "internet_store.web_ui.servlet")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resourceViewResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resourceViewResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/internet_store/");
    resourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resourceViewResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resourceViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resourceViewResolver.setCheckExistence(false);
    return resourceViewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/", "classpath:/templates/internet_store/")
            .setCachePeriod(320000)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable("estore");
}
}
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruofW.png)

[Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4rbs.png)

This code return error in browser ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. If in controller set return "redirect:/foo" then redirect not doing too. Example below.

`code`

```
@GetMapping(value = "/back_client")
public String backButtonClientFormPressed() {
    
    return "service/service";
}
```

index.html have controller with method

`code`

```
@GetMapping(value = "/index")
public String index(ModelMap modelMap) {
    updatePage();

    Path resourceDirectory = Paths.get("resources");

    modelMap.addAttribute("error", "");
    refreshData(modelMap);
    return "index";
}
```

Change service/service to redirect:/index going to error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Maybe problems with resources path? Thank You for You attention.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

Need delete response.sendRedirect("/index.html"); from servlet class and add

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```